# Vue array RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, filter, match

I need to filter a list with checkboxes.

This how loop the array from VUEX

```
<div class="checkbox" v-for="brand in brands" :key="brand.id">
   <input name="brands" type="checkbox" :value="brand.name" v-model="checkedBrand" />
   <label for="brands">{{brand.name}}</label>
</div>
```

This is my function

```
filteredList() {
      if (this.checkedBrand.length > 0) {
        return this.shoes.filter(shoe => {
          return shoe.brand.match(
            new RegExp(
              this.checkedBrand.forEach(check => {
                return +check + "|";
              }),
              "g"
            )
          );
        });
      } else {
        return this.shoes;
      }
    }
```

When it's new RegExp(checkedBrand[0]+'|'+checkedBrand[1], 'g'), but I don't want to be hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

```
filteredList() {
  if (this.checkedBrand.length > 0) {
    return this.shoes.filter(shoe => {
      return shoe.brand.match(
        new RegExp(
          this.checkedBrand.join('|'),
          "g"
        )
      );
    });
  } else {
    return this.shoes;
  }
}
```